# How to access a global picklist in Visualforce?

Tags: visualforce, global-picklist

I want to use values from a global picklist in a visualforce page.
How do I reference a global picklist?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It doesn't look like it's possible to access global picklists in Apex/Visualforce right now. At least, not the same way that you'd access a fieldset or a (Hierarchy) Custom Setting.

The best information I was able to find on this was through the chatter group on the success community for the global/restricted picklist feature. Specifically, [this single post](https://success.salesforce.com/0D53000002ajdvc) in the group's discussion.

For the time being, it looks like the only way to reference global picklist values in Visualforce would be to create a custom field that uses your global picklist, and then reference that field in your Visualforce page.

It's also good to keep in mind that global picklists are still in an 'open pilot'. Until the open beta begins (looks to be currently planned for Summer '16/ API v37), you'll need to have support activate the feature in production orgs if you want to use (in production) what you're working on.

Comment: <apex:selectList value="{!selectedCountry2}" multiselect="false" size="1">
                <apex:selectOptions value="{$new_global_picklist}"/>
            </apex:selectList>

Comment: i try this. it is worng because new_global_picklist is not an api name its an developer name.

Comment: I think you misunderstood what I was saying. Let's say you have a custom picklist field on your object called `uses_global_picklist__c` which, as the name implies, is set to use values from a global picklist that you've defined. You'd be able to access the values of that global picklist _indirectly_ by referencing your custom picklist `{!uses_global_picklist__c}`. Global picklists are currently not accessible via a global variable (which is what you tried to do with the `{$<name>}` syntax.)

Comment: ok i get it now.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [metadata API wrappers](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi), you can query [GlobalValueSet](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_globalvalueset.htm) object.